# Solving a special system of N+1 equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta_i$ with $i=1,...,N$ be known real constants, with $0<\alpha<1$ and $0<\beta_i<1$ for all $i=1,...,N$. I need to solve the system of $N+1$ equations defined as

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
z\,\left(1-x_1\,x_2\,\cdots x_N\right)+x_1\,x_2\,\cdots x_N &=& \alpha\\
z\,\left(1-x_1\right)+x_1 & = & \beta_1 \\
z\,\left(1-x_2\right)+x_2 & = & \beta_2 \\
                          & \vdots &  \\
z\,\left(1-x_N\right)+x_N & = & \beta_N
\end{array}
\right.,
$$

where $z,x_1,...,x_N$ are the $N+1$-unknowns.

I know that for  $N=2$ there is a unique solution given by (verified also with software)

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
z       &=& \frac{\alpha-\beta_1\,\beta_2}{1+\alpha-\beta_1-\beta_2} \\
x_1 &=& \frac{\alpha-\beta_1}{\beta_2-1}\\
x_2 &=& \frac{\alpha-\beta_2}{\beta_1-1}
\end{array}
\right.,
$$
But at the present time I didn't go any further and I suspect there is no way to find an analytical solution or that there could be more than one solutions. A simple substitution gives that $z$ must solve the equation

$$
\left(\beta_1-z\right)\,\left(\beta_2-z\right)\cdots\left(\beta_N-z\right) = \left(\alpha-z\right)\,\left(1-z\right)^{N-1}
$$

so $z$ must one of the roots of a polynomial of degree $N$, which however it does not seem to give any help. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: For $N=2$, is $z= \frac{\alpha-\beta_1\,\beta_2}{1-\alpha-\beta_1-\beta_2}$ or $z= \frac{\alpha-\beta_1\,\beta_2}{1+\alpha-\beta_1-\beta_2}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, It's $z= \frac{\alpha-\beta_1\,\beta_2}{1+\alpha-\beta_1-\beta_2}$, I re-edited and now it's correct.

Comment: For $N=3$, it is already a nighmare with multiple solutions. Just in case you want the system looks nicer, add one equation $z(1-t)+t=\alpha$ where $t=\prod_{i=1}^N x_i$ but this does not change the problem.